# Python plot forced sorting dates alphabetically instead of chronologically

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, seaborn

I am plotting my dataset (Mortality in England and Wales against region) and the dates on the X-axis keep sorting alphabetically. It goes Apr 06, Apr 07,..., Feb 06, Feb 07,..., Sep-13,Sep-14.

I want them to be in chronological order (Like it is in my data set) Is there any way to turn off forced sorting? I am using matplot lib and seaborn for this plot.

Also if anyone knows a way to write out this code without repeating the code 13 times I would be happy to hear it.

My code is as follows

```
plt.figure(figsize=(48,12))

sns.lineplot(data=Regional,x='Date',y='England and Wales')
sns.lineplot(data=Regional,x='Date',y='England')
sns.lineplot(data=Regional,x='Date',y='North East')
sns.lineplot(data=Regional,x='Date',y='North West')
sns.lineplot(data=Regional,x='Date',y='Yorkshire and the Humber')
sns.lineplot(data=Regional,x='Date',y='East Midlands')
sns.lineplot(data=Regional,x='Date',y='West Midlands')
sns.lineplot(data=Regional,x='Date',y='East of England')
sns.lineplot(data=Regional,x='Date',y='Greater London')
sns.lineplot(data=Regional,x='Date',y='South East')
sns.lineplot(data=Regional,x='Date',y='South West')
sns.lineplot(data=Regional,x='Date',y='Wales')
sns.lineplot(data=Regional,x='Date',y='Non Residents')

plt.legend(['England and Wales','England','North East','North West','Yorkshire and the Humber','East Midlands','West Midlands','East of England','Greater London','South East','South West','Wales','Non Residents'])
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Turn your date into datetime type before plotting.

Comment: your dates probably aren't actually dates, but instead strings. Also, you should melt your data and pass the resulting region column as your "hue" to a single call to `lineplot`

Comment: Why not use Matplotlib? No sorting happens behind the scenes unless you force it to

Comment: If you put your dates into [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) they will sort properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, using [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and datetime format will likely solve your issues. You can use `pd.to_datetime` to convert your dates to datetime format. Assuming your strings are `'Jul-06'` format, you can specify your format is `'%b-%y'`. Otherwise, you can check this [table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for the correct format specifier.

`pd.melt` can reformat your dataframe to plot using a single line of code. Assuming your dataframe contains columns only for date and regions, you can use the following code to pull everything together:

```
Regional['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Regional['Date'], format='%b-%y')
Regional = pd.melt(Regional, id_vars=['Date'], var_name='Region', value_name='Mortality')
sns.lineplot(data=Regional, x='Date', y='Mortality', hue='Region')
```

Comment: Thankyou for this, usually I would use hue but I cannot wrap my head around how to organise my CSV to have region as a header. I currently have it oragnised to have date as the row and regions as the column but there is no header for region.

It looks roughly like this

Date, England, North East,.... Wales
Jan - 06, 300, 345, 654
Feb -06 .... etc 
So all my headers are separate regions

Comment: I see pandas.melt repeated the date 14 times for each region. I did initially considered this but thought there was a more efficient way but I suppose not, thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of melting you can also create a `pd.MultiIndex` to automatically `plot` as desired with `matplotlib`:

```
Regional['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Regional['Date'])
Regional = Regional.set_index('Date')
Regional.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Region', col) for col in Regional.columns])
Regional.plot(ax=ax, title='Daily Mortality Rate by Region', ylabel='Mortality')
plt.legend(title='Regions', labels=[col[1] for col in Regional.columns])
```

The `seaborn` way (See other answer) is a bit cleaner, but this is just a `matplotlib` solution.